# Python - Pull values from list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
list_1 = [['1','a'],['1','b'],['1','c'],['2','a'],['2','d'], ['1','c']]
```

How can I iterate through the list to append the second value to another list while grouping by the first value. So it would look something like this:

```
list_2 = [['a','b','c','c'],['a','d']]
```

Comment: Suggestion use `defaultdict(list)` for output instead of list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be in two steps - first, find the unique 'keys' in `list_1`, then filter `list_1` into multiple lists based on those keys.

```
unique_keys = set(elem[0] for elem in list_1)
list_2 = [[elem[1] for elem in list_1 if elem[0] == key]
         for key in unique_keys]
# [['a', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']]
```

The set is ordered in order of last occurrence of any given `key`, which is why the output is backwards from what you'd expect. To fix this, do `set(elem[0] for elem in reversed(list_1))` instead.

Comment: The time complexity is `O(n^2)` right. Using `defaultdict(list)` reduces it to `O(n)`.

Comment: @Ch3steR You're absolutely right, and I've upvoted your answer. At the time I was too lazy to reread the `defaultdict` docs, and so presented a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Your answer is expressive and pure python approach very good for python beginners. So upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res=defaultdict(list)

for key,val in list_1:
    res[key]+=val
#res looks like this {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], '2': ['a', 'd']}
print(list(res.values())) # [['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], ['a', 'd']]
```